# Qualtrics Block Submit Button

Tags: qualtrics

I want to block NextButton not using disableNextButton Method in Qualtrics.

```
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    function myFunction() {
        var c = confirm("JUST for TEST");
        if (c == true) {
            this.clickNextButton();
        } else {
            //I need your help :(
        }
    }
document.getElementById('NextButton').onclick = function() {
    if(document.getElementById('NextButton').nodeName= "submit") {
        myFunction();
    }
};
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Do you want your NextButton to be visible? If so, just use:

```
$('NextButton').disabled=true;
```

You can also hide it:

```
$('NextButton').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

**What I've understood:**
When the next button is pressed, you want to check if a particular *condition* is met or not. 
If the *condition* is met you want the next button to work as is.
If the *condition* doesn't meet you want to prevent the click's functionality.

**Solution**: Try using event.preventDefault() when the condition doesn't meet. 
You need not write this.clickNextButton(). That is triggered by default.